# how to capture http response from Java SWT browser component

Tags: java, browser, swt, response

Is it posible to capture http response that comping back from request im making in java SWT browser component ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least if you're using a Mozilla based SWT browser. In that case you could implement a nsIObserver and take a look at the response via the observe() method.

Here's a snippet: http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet321.java?view=co

Comment: Eclipse snippets are on Git now: [Snippet321](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet321.java)